# C#: Select row from DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a form with a DataGridView (of 3 columns) and a Button. Every time the user clicks on a button, I want the get the values stored in the 1st column of that row.

Here is the code I have:

```
    private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ProductsGrid.Rows)
        {
            if (this.ProductsGrid.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
            {
             // get information of 1st column from the row
             string value = this.ProductsGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

However when I click on myButton, the this.ProductsGrid.SelectedRows.Count is 0. Also, how do I ensure that the user selects only one row and not multiple rows?
Does this code look right?

Comment: You don't need to iterate (foreach) over all the rows of the DataGrid to get only the first SelectedRow. The foreach loop is a waste of time here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Set [DataGridView.MultiSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect.aspx)=false and [DataGridView.SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode.aspx) = FullRowSelect.  This will make it so the user can only select a single row at a time.

Comment: I had to use dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

Answer (score 1):

SelectedRows only returns the rows if the entire row is selected (you can turn on RowSelect on the datagridview if you want). The better option is to go with `SelectedCells`

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cell = this.ProductsGrid.SelectedCells[0];
    var row = this.ProductsGrid.Rows[cell.RowIndex];
    string value = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't need to both iterate over all rows in your grid and access the collection of SelectedRows. If you skip iteratating and use the SelectedRows collection, then your problem is probably an incorrect SelectionMode:

> The SelectionMode property must be set
>   to FullRowSelect or RowHeaderSelect
>   for the SelectedRows property to be
>   populated with selected rows.

(from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the grid similar to an array:

```
ProductsGrid[ProductsGrid.SelectedColumns[0].Index, ProductsGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value;
```

By selecting the indexes from the first index of the SelectedRowsCollection and SelectedColumnsCollection you'll grab the first value if multiple rows are selected.

---

You can lock the user to selecting only a single row by setting the `MultiSelect` property on the DataGridView. Alternatively you make the `CellClick` event perform:

```
ProductsGrid.ClearSelection();
ProductsGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedRows.Count` returns the number of entire rows that are currently selected. You probably want to use `SelectedCells.Count`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the `.BoundItem`